# Android "Control" Gallery

Tags: android

Is there a community site with a set of custom controls or how they call it Views, where one can grab and reuse or publish something more advanced than the standard set of UI components?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenIntents.org has a bunch](http://www.openintents.org/en/libraries), but it is not complete. I have been begging for somebody to create Teh Most Awesome Android Component Catalog, with all sorts of nice searching and such, but nobody has taken me up on it yet, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I'm not really sure if Android supports packaging ready-to-use Views in external jars, but it would be really awesome as it seems everyone exploits same tricks with standard controls and creates similar custom controls missing from standard control set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this great app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns

very helpfull